# SSH GitLab pull always asks for password

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

(Git**Lab** specifically! (No issues with GitHub))
I'm trying to create a script to pull a project from `main` **GitLab** branch without asking for password. A couple of remote computers have a kiosk-mode project. It's kind of boring to always connect manually to them - instead of having a cron-job to pull *automagically*.

I've setup to use **SSH** and created and added my SSH ed25519 key.
Added the proper `url` in `./.git/config` like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.com:<ME>/<REPO>.git
```

<sup>where `<ME>` and `<REPO>` are my username and repository :)</sup>

**Using `git pull` or `fetch` *always* asks for password**. The same does not happens on my GitHub repos.

The only way I managed to make it work was using a [**Personal Access Token**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://oauth2:<MY P. A. TOKEN>@gitlab.com/<ME>/<REPO>.git
```

But I don't like the token being in plaintext and having to do stuff out of the scope of SSH handshakes.

Is there something Git**Lab**-specific I'm missing? Every help-page I was able to search just talks about setting the correct SSH URI (git@gitlab.com..... etc) which I already did.  But every time I trigger a `git pull` it **keeps asking for password**.

Windows. Git Bash.

Appreciate any help, trick or insight.

Comment: Does your ssh key have a passphrase protecting it?

Comment: @AdamMarshall It was. Silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your ssh key is generated with a passphrase and that's why it asks you for the passphrase.

---

### SSH login without password

Your aim

You want to use Linux and OpenSSH to automate your tasks. Therefore you need an automatic login from host A / user a to Host B / user b. You don't want to enter any passwords, because you want to call ssh from a within a shell script.

How to do it
First log in on A as user a and generate a pair of authentication keys. Do not enter a passphrase:

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase: (THIS IS THE CATCH, just press enter here to leave it empty): 
Enter same passphrase again: (press enter again)
Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A

a@A:~> ssh-copy-id remote_username@remote_domain

or

a@A:~> ssh-copy-id remote_username@remote_IP

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
remote_username@remote_domain password:
```

There it will ask you to enter the password for the remote user on that remote server

```
Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh -p '22' 'remote_username@remote_domain'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Now try to login with

```
a@A:~> ssh remote_username@remote_domain
```

and you should get in

---

Source: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Gitlab docs specifically instruct you to use a passphrase : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#generate-an-ssh-key-pair

Comment: Yes, because it's more secure. But the sole purpose of making the ssh key WITHOUT password is so that you don't have to insert password, you just ssh into the server automatically. Probably more than 95% developers don't set the password because we are lazy and the chances for the key to get stolen or hacked are the same as if someone steals your laptop/pc

Comment: Right, but the correct way is through setting `~/.ssh/config`. That way you avoid your key getting stolen/hacked *and* relieve yourself of the need to enter passphrase on every pull or push

Comment: `ssh-copy-id my_gitlab_username@gitlab.com` ... result: "my_gitlab_username@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)"... NB OS is Linux Mint 20. The other solution you suggest is "remote_username@remote_IP"... how do I find out the remote IP (i.e. of Gitlab)?

Comment: gitlab.com is the official website of gitlab... you shouldn't be connecting to that web site... all these examples are for self hosted gitlab... when you make your own public server (buy a domain name and host storage provider) I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have an interesting edge case: Can connect to multiple servers using my SSH key that does not have a password on it, but one specific server always asks for a password. What could be causing this (besides a phishing attempt that I am aware is a concern)?

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved this problem for my [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com) repos: I've just followed the steps in their tutorial at [Use SSH keys to communicate with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html).

There they explain how to create keys, but since mine already existed all I had to do was to follow the steps in the section [Configure SSH to point to a different directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#configure-ssh-to-point-to-a-different-directory). They're only:

1. Type the commands

   ```bash
   eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
   ssh-add <full path to private SSH key>
   ```

   In Linux, the SSH keys are usually saved in the folder `~/.ssh/`
2. Edit the `~/.ssh/config` file to have the lines

   ```
   Host gitlab.com`
      PreferredAuthentications publickey
      IdentityFile <full path to private SSH key>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows, even the ssh -T git@gitlab.domain.com didn't work!
The solution was a lot simpler that I thought: I had to open git bash as an administrator

Comment: Hey, just FYI to others coming here, this doesn't work if you're using git on a remote server. The 'run as admin' setting is (of course) only local.